# Irssi delete default channels, servers and networks

Tags: irc, irssi

Irssi comes with a lot of networks and servers in the default configuration.

How can I:

1. Delete all networks and servers in the default configuration?

   `/NETWORK REMOVE Networkname` and `/SERVER PURGE Servername` did not bring any changes
2. Add some servers to automatically connect?

   ```
   /server add -auto -network test -ssl -ssl_verify 192.168.2.1 -port 7001
   ```

When I try to connect, I get:

> warning Could not verify TLS servers certificate: self signed certificate 11:24 -!- Irssi: Connection lost to 192.168.2.1

Comment: What version of irssi do you have? It looks like they made a change in [0.8.18](https://github.com/irssi/irssi/commit/6d6e672e8e27469bd08704edb96c3e0fa9ef898f) related to this. Prior to that version removing the network would not remove associated servers and channels.

Comment: i use Irssi v1.0.7-1~ on Debiian